# Golang Thread-Pool dispatcher purpose and order

Tags: multithreading, go, threadpool, goroutine

I just finished writing a simple proxy application in go: The code gets UDP packet from one interface, encrypt the data and then send it to another interface using TCP.

Currently, I'm using three goroutines: one for receiving, one for encrypting and one for sending the data. I just started to try and find ways to improve the efficiency and speed of the code.

First, I thought about creating a new goroutine for each packet needed to be encrypted but after reading the following two blog posts I understood that this isn't the right thing to do:

1. http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/
2. http://nesv.github.io/golang/2014/02/25/worker-queues-in-go.html

After reading those two I found myself with two questions about thread-pool:

1. Why should I use thread-pool and not just create "x" goroutines for encryption with a common channel? Each goroutine will process the packet whenever he can. Is there a downside to this approach ?
2. If I want to keep the order of the packets, meaning that the first packet from the UDP will be the first sent by the TCP, then the second and so on... and only want to parallelise on the encryption part of the program, can I count on the multiple goroutine\thread-pool to keep the right order ? I guess that the answer is no, but would like to know if anyone has a solution for this issue.

Thank

Comment: What do you mean by #1? Creating X goroutines with a common channel is conceptually the same as a "thread pool".

Comment: In the two blog post the use of thread pool is without a common channel.  Both program use a different channel to every goroutine with a dispatcher.

Comment: take a look at semaphores

Answer (score 0):

1. The purpose of a worker pool is to *limit* the concurrency of tasks executed by the workers.  This is useful when performing tasks that require
   sufficient resources (CPU, memory, etc.), and running too many tasks at the
   same time would exhaust resources.
2. With a worker pool, tasks are dispatched to available workers.  If separate tasks (in your case packets to encrypt) are dispatched to separate workers, then you cannot determine which worker (goroutine) is executed first, and will not know the order that tasks are completed.

If you want to parallelize the encryption tasks, but need to maintain order, then an index can be assigned to each packet/task as input is received.  When the worker pool is done with each task, the output can be put into a sorted container such as a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) where sorting is done according to index.  As soon as the encrypted packet with the next index in the sequence is at the top of the heap, it is popped from the heap and sent.